# Really old post showing up in the low quality post

Tags: discussion, review-queues, low-quality-posts

I was doing some old quality post and I came across a really old post

[Remove Primary Key constraint from a column(sql server 2005)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1841984/1380867)

It should be a comment but I don't think that at the time there could be comments.

What should I do?

Comment: There could be comments at the time. See underneath the question, there's a comment that was posted on the same date, before the answer was posted. So flag it as not an answer. The author did have enough rep to post a comment, so there's no reason he has to post a comment as an answer.

Comment: @mmking Post your comment as an answer.

Comment: @JaredBurrows Done.

Comment: Even if they didn't have comments at the time, it's *still* not an answer and should be deleted.

Answer (score 4):

There could be comments at the time. See underneath the question, there's a comment that was posted on the same date, before the answer was posted. So flag it as not an answer. The author did have enough rep to post a comment, so there's no reason he has to post a comment as an answer.

It's deleted now.